# IMEI Plugin Phonegap not working

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

---

I need to fetch the IMEI Number of the android device using phonegap application.

I found an IMEI plugin code on github https://github.com/macdonst/IMEI/tree/master/v2.2.0 I want to use it with the latest version of Phonegap (3.3.0, API 19) what changes should be made to this code and what procedure should I follow to install it?
Kindly provide detailed installation instructions, as I am a complete novice at this.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try it? do you get any error?

Comment: I made the plugin.xml file by looking at those of other plugins. Then used the cordova plugin add command to"succesfully" add the plugin to my project. There are no errors displayed but the imei number(see index.html) is never displayed when the app is run.
The source of my plugin.xml is : http://pastebin.com/F3DpRznp

Comment: do you have the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" /> on your manifest?

Comment: Yes, I have already added it to the androidmanifest.xml file

Comment: try to add it manually instead using the plugin.xml

Comment: I did it as well, I added the .java, .js ans the .xml file to the org.IMEI.IMEIPlugin folder under the plugins folder, I added <feature name="imei">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.IMEI.IMEIPlugin.IMEIPlugin" />
        <param name="onload" value="true" />
    </feature>
to the config.xml file, and I also added the imei.js file to the www folder, but it still displays nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure imei.js in the plugin has the good structure for using clobbers in plugin.xml. 
try to replace

```
<js-module src="imei.js" name="imei">
    <clobbers target="imei" />
</js-module>
```

with

```
<js-module src="imei.js" name="imei">
    <runs />
</js-module>
```

or change imei.js to look like js in other plugins.

Comment: Have you checked logs in logcat? is window.plugins.imei defined when you try to use the plugin? (maybe you should edit your question with more details on what's happening now that you modified the plugin)

Answer (score 1):

this question is old but still not answered, It may help someone else in future.
Install this plugin using the following line inside your cordova/phonegap project

`cordova plugin add com.simonmacdonald.imeiplugin`

call it using the following script:

```
  function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("We got device ready");
    window.plugins.IMEIPlugin.get(function(imei) {
        alert("imei: " + imei);
    }, function() {
        alert("fail");
    });
}
```